# Using parameter input outside a function in python

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

Last week I have started to learn a bit of Python (using Pycharm). Using several websites and youtube videos I am slowely but surely learning the basics. To challenge myself I'm trying to make myself a 'rock, paper, scissors'-game. The game consists of 2 players entering their 'hand'.
My struggle is wanting to check wether their input matches my list called 'options' using the function checkinput()
The problem: When checkinput() is activated and the while loop is activated (i.e. rock, paper or scissors not in options). The 'whichhand = input(...)' that follows does not seem to save the input into the requested variable which would be 'handp1' or 'handp2'.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

```
print("Welcome to Rock, Paper or Scissors!")
options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]    
namep1 = input("Player 1, what is your name? ")
namep2 = input("Player 2, what is your name? ")

def placeyourbets():
    global handp1
    global handp2
    handp1 = input("Okay " + namep1 + ", enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    checkinput(handp1, namep1)
    handp2 = input("Okay " + namep2 + ", enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    checkinput(handp2, namep2)
    return handp1, handp2
def checkinput(whichhand, whichname):
    while whichhand.lower() not in options:
        print("Error!\nEnter 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'.")
        whichhand = input("Okay " + whichname + ", enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
placeyourbets()
```

Comment: When you call `checkinput(handp1, namep1)` you are passing references to the values those identifiers reference, not to the identifiers. `whichhand =` in `checkinput` does **not** change anything in `placeyourbets`. I'd recommend reading e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm experienced just as much, so take everything I say with a grain of salt.

I looked at your code and after wrapping my tiny brain over what you're trying to achieve I found a solution.

```
print("Welcome to Rock, Paper or Scissors!")
options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
name_p_1 = input("Player 1, what is your name? ")
name_p_2 = input("Player 2, what is your name? ")


def place_your_bets():
    hand_p_1 = input(f"Okay {name_p_1}, enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    hand_p_1 = check_input(hand_p_1, name_p_1)
    hand_p_2 = input(f"Okay {name_p_2}, enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    hand_p_2 = check_input(hand_p_2, name_p_2)
    return hand_p_1, hand_p_2


def check_input(which_hand, which_name):
    while which_hand.lower() not in options:
        print("Error! Invalid input."
              "\nTry again, enter 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scissors'.")
        which_hand = input(f"Okay {which_name}, enter your hand (Rock, Paper or Scissors): ")
    return which_hand


choice_player_1, choice_player_2 = place_your_bets()
print(choice_player_1)
print(choice_player_2)
```

I renamed the variables in way that I'm used to work with, but that has nothing to do with the solution.

So, first thing I did was I removed the global tag for `hand_p_1` and `hand_p_2`, because quite frankly, I wasn't sure what exactly it was accomplishing.

Second off and most importantly, I noticed that your `checkinput` function doesn't have a `return` line, which basically makes the inputs you enter in it, vanish after the function is completed

And lastly the way you executed the `palceyourbets` function doesn't store the inputs, so I added two variables, `choice_player_1` and `choice_player_2` that store the return values of that function

As I said, I'm quite new to python and coding in general, but I hope I've helped.